# drop big table freeze server

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds

I am using amazon rds mysql 5.6 master instance and 4 slaves.
there is big table with 800 GIB size that i want to drop it for releasing  space. But when i execute drop command, the server entering to "freeze mode" and cant execute any kind of commands.

similar issue : https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44757

I need to remove it from production rds.

- there is no transactions on this table
- innodb_file_per_table  = ON

I though about Deleting rows in chunks for not create big lag for slaves and then (optional optimize) drop the table.

Comment: What if you `TRUNCATE TABLE` first?

Comment: i tried , the server stacking . becouse of the high amount of data

Answer (score 1):

What exact version?

`DELETE` on a huge table will take a huge amount of time because it is building an "undo" log in case of a crash.  Don't use that technique.

What was the value of `innodb_file_per_table` *when the table was built*?

- If `OFF` (or `0`), the table is in `ibdata1`, which will not shrink and return space to the OS.  It will only free up blocks for subsequent use.
- If `ON` (or `1`), then `DROP TABLE` will be much faster, but still not instantaneous.
- If you have `FOREIGN KEYs` connecting the table (in either direction), well, let's see them.  (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

If you need to delete a big part of a table, [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) are several techniques.  This discusses how to do the delete in chunks, and takes Replication issues into account.

Comment: Hey , MySQL 5.6.39 , innodb_file_per_table = 1 when table created , it dont have any foreign keys . already checked this one  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Comment: Alas, I am town to "clutching at straws".  RDS has a bunch of different things going on in the OS; the only "big" step in `DROP TABLE` (when file_per_table) is actual releasing of all the blocks to the OS.  So, I _guess_ this is an RDS problem.  (I know MySQL, but not RDS.)